# ko.mapping.toJS not working on child observable array property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

When I call ko.mapping.toJS on the child property Tags, which is an observableArray, the resulting JS object is mapped as [{}, {}, {}]; any idea on why the properties of the child property is not getting mapped?

```
// Question
sv.QuestionService = function () {
    var _saveQuestion = function (question, callback) {
        var tags = [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: "food"
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: "career"
            },
            {
                Id: 3,
                Name: "fax"
            }
        ];

        $.each(tags, function (index, item) {
            question.Tags.push({ Id: 1, Name: "food" });
        });

        console.log(question.Tags());

        $.ajax("/Interview/saveQuestion", {
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(question),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: callback
        });
    };


    return {
        saveQuestion: _saveQuestion
    };
}();

// Question view model
sv.QuestionViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    if (!data.QuestionType) {
        data.QuestionType = "Not Specified";
    }
    this.Tags = ko.observableArray([]);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    this.QuestionStatus = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.IsApproved ? "Pending Interview Question" : "Approved Interview Question"
    }, this);

    this.TagsText(this.TagsText() || "None");
};

// C#
public class InterviewQuestionViewModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public long? QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string RequestorName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdminApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string TagsText { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public InterviewQuestionViewModel() {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}

public class Tag {
    [Description("tag_id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Description("tag_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Tag() {
        IsActive = false;
    }
}

// Approved Questions view model
sv.ApprovedQuestionListViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.questions = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.questionCount = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.questions().length;
    }, this);

    this.load = function () {
        sv.QuestionService.getApprovedQuestions(function (data) {
            var mapped = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
                return new sv.QuestionViewModel(item);
            });
            self.questions(mapped);
        });
    }.bind(this);
};
```

Comment: Hi Abe.  Your QuestionService.saveQuestion function appears to be correctly serializing your array via the call to ko.mapping.toJSON (see my answer below).  If you could post the portion of your client-side javascript that is calling the function, it might be possible to track down where the issue lies.  But the actually function appears to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your ko.mapping code in your QuestionService.saveQuestion function is working fine.  I can't really tell what is causing your difficulty, since I can't see the entire application.  But if I exercise your QuestionService.saveQuestion function, it is correctly pushing the content of the function-scope "tags" variable into the question.Tags observable array, and your call to ko.mapping.toJSON is correctly generating a JSON-formatted string that can be passed across the wire.

Here is the client-side code I ran to exercise your QuestionService.saveQuestion function:

```
<script>
    sv = {};
    sv.QuestionService = function () {
        var _saveQuestion = function (question, callback) {
            var tags = [
            { Id: 1, Name: "food" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "career" },
            { Id: 3, Name: "fax" }  ];
            $.each(tags, function (index, item) {
                question.Tags.push(item);
            });
            console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(question));

           $.ajax("/Home/saveQuestion", {
                data: ko.mapping.toJSON(question),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: sv.Completed
            });
        };
        return {
           saveQuestion: _saveQuestion
        };
    } ();
    sv.Completed = function (data) {     
        alert(data.message);
    };

    var input = { Tags : ko.observableArray([])};
    sv.QuestionService.saveQuestion(input, sv.Completed);
</script>
```

When I run this code, I see the correctly serialized JSON string debug window:

```
{"Tags":[{"Id":1,"Name":"food"},{"Id":2,"Name":"career"},{"Id":3,"Name":"fax"}]}
```

and I see the an array of C# Tag objects on the server-side with three members:

[image]

So your QuestionService.saveQuestion function is correctly using ko.mapping.toJSON to serialize the portion of your ViewModel to a JSON string.  The problems you are experiencing must lie in other portions of your code.

Comment: Hi Joe, the ko.mapping.toJSON does serialize the Tags child property, but somehow the properties Id and Name are empty or null.

Comment: Hi Abe.  In the sample code I posted, the Id and NAme properties are being populated and correctly sent to the server.  I updated by screen shot to show that.  If you could post more of your javascript code, including the call to QuestionService.saveQuestion, I'll see if I can reproduce the issue.  But for now I can't.  Thanks.

Comment: One difference seems to be that I am using ko.mapping.fromJS on your variable input.